# Error when displaying webpage in columns

Tags: php, html, css

I am doing a dynamic site in php. I have divided the page into 2 columns. The first section shows a person's profile and the second section shows the article written by him/her. The problem is when i am adding more than one article. The second article is coming below the profile. I have tried using class clearfix. Its not working. Can someone please help me?
[This is my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpOFd.png)

```html
 <div class="container">
 <?php
 session_start();
 $q = $_SESSION['id'];
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("demo_db",$con);

$sql="select * from personal_details where id=$q";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($ar=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
 
 
?>
<div>
  <div class="row">
   <div style="background-color:rgba(125, 178, 194, 0.43); margin-bottom:10px;" class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
     <img style="margin:20px;" src="uploads/<?php echo $ar[17]; ?>">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
     <h3><b>Dr. <?php echo $ar[1];?></b></h3>
     <h5><?php echo $ar[8];?>, <?php echo $ar[12];?></h5>
     <h5><?php echo $ar[2];?>, <?php echo $ar[7];?> years of experience</h5>
     <p><?php echo $ar[16];?></p>
     </div>
    </div>
        <div style="margin:20px;">
        <h4><b>Services</b></h4>
        <hr>
        <ul>
        <li>
        <h5><?php echo $ar[18]; ?></h5>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <h4><b>Specialisations</b></h4>
        <hr>
        <ul>
        <li>
        <h5><?php echo $ar[2]; ?></h5>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <h4><b>Education</b></h4>
        <hr>
        <ul>
        <li>
        <h5><?php echo $ar[8]; ?> - <?php echo $ar[9]; ?> , <?php echo $ar[10]; ?> , <?php echo $ar[11];?></h5>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
        <li>
        <h5><?php echo $ar[12]; ?> - <?php echo $ar[13]; ?> , <?php echo $ar[14]; ?> , <?php echo $ar[15];?></h5>
        </li>
        </ul>
        
        </div>
        
   </div>
    
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <h3>Articles by <?php echo $ar[1];?></h3><?php } ?>
  <hr>
  <?php
  $sql1="select * from article_tb where id=$q";
$res1=mysql_query($sql1);
while($ar=mysql_fetch_array($res1))
{
 $_SESSION['id'] = $q;
 ?>
  <h4><b><?php echo $ar[1]; ?></b></h4>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7">
     <img src="uploads/<?php echo $ar[3]; ?>" width="170px" height="88">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
     
    &nbsp; <form action="blog.php">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="read" value="read" />
</form>
    </div>
   </div>
      <hr>
 
 
  
 
  </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Can you put the generated HTML in the snippet instead of the PHP, please?

Comment: Would you mind creating a minimum complete verified instance?

Comment: I have attached an image with the question which shows the error. The second article image and 'read' button is coming below the profile. I want it to be on the right, below the first article